# Como arrumar hover em section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Fiz um site com base em um *template* e estou com um probleminha quando clico em algum lugar, ele desce mas não da o efeito de `hover`, ele só da esse efeito de `hover` em 3 `section`, antes das 2 últimas que são "contato" e "área do cliente".
código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Eduardo Gonçalves Fotografia</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_misc.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_style.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/1437171586.ico">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
        <![endif]-->


        <div class="site-main" id="sTop">
            <div class="site-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <ul class="social-icons">
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/estudiodeimagem?pnref=lhc" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://instagram.com/estudiodeimagem/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
                    </div> <!-- /.row -->
                </div> <!-- /.container -->
                <div class="main-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="menu-wrapper">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="logo-wrapper col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-8">

                                </div> <!-- /.logo-wrapper -->
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-4 main-menu text-right">
                                    <ul class="menu-first hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#services">O Fotógrafo</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#our-team">Últimos Eventos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#contact1">Área do Cliente</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                                </div> <!-- /.main-menu -->
                            </div> <!-- /.row -->
                        </div> <!-- /#menu-wrapper -->
                        <div class="menu-responsive hidden-md hidden-lg">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#services">O Fotógrafo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#our-team">Últimos Eventos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact1">Área do Cliente</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- /.menu-responsive -->
                    </div> <!-- /.container -->
                </div> <!-- /.main-header -->
            </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
            <div class="site-slider">
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide5.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide6.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <img src="images/slide7.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                </div> <!-- /.slider -->
            </div> <!-- /.site-slider -->
        </div> <!-- /.site-main -->


        <div class="content-section" id="services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>O Fotógrafo</h2>

                    </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="images/boi.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="team-overlay">
                                <h3>Eduardo Gonçalves</h3>
                                <ul class="social">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/estudiodeimagemfotografia?fref=hovercard" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- /.team-overlay -->
                        </div> <!-- /.member-thumb -->
                         <p class="text-center"><br>Com 33 anos de idade, 5 de fotografia e muitos casamentos em seu portfólio. Eduardo Gonçalves vem ganhando grande destaque entre os melhores fotógrafos do interior paulista.
Seu objetivo é captar o momento do jeito que ele aconteceu sem interferir em nada, conseguindo fazer uma mesclagem com a fotografia clássica e a criativa conseguindo atingir todos os públicos e emocionando várias gerações. Nosso propósito é ter uma fotografia de grande qualidade e menos careta.
            </p>
                    </div> <!-- /.team-member -->    


                    <div class="team-member col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="member-thumb">
                            <img src="images/vah.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="team-overlay">
                                <h3>Valéria Gonçalves</h3>
                                <ul class="social">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/goncalvesvah?fref=hovercard" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>

                                </ul>

                            </div> <!-- /.team-overlay -->
                        </div> <!-- /.member-thumb -->
              <p class="text-center"><br>A paixão pela fotografia foi despertada dentro de mim quando meu marido e sócio Eduardo Gonçalves me deu a primeira câmera e pediu para eu fazer uma foto. Naquele momento vimos que eu tinha um olhar diferenciado, conseguia ver o que os outros não viam em uma simples cena. E a partir daí fui me aperfeiçoando, e hoje trabalho com o que mais gosto, o amor. Meu maior prazer é fotografar o amor e deixar ele para sempre eternizado pelas minhas lentes.
            </p>

                    </div> <!-- /.team-member -->  
                 </div>

              </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </div> <!-- /#services -->



        <div class="content-section" id="portfolio">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>Portfolio</h2>

                    </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
             <?php   
               require("classe/conexao.class.php");
                $c = new Conexao();
                $c->Conecta();
                $c->SelecionaBase();

                $portfolio = "portfolio";
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portfolio where execao = '$portfolio' order by id_portfolio desc LIMIT 12") or die (mysql_error());
                while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    $titulo = $a['nome'];
                        $categoria = $a['categoria'];
                        $imagem = $a['img'];
                        $id = $a['id_portfolio'];
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                print"      

                    <div class=\"portfolio-item col-md-3 col-sm-6\">
                        <div class=\"portfolio-thumb\">
                            <img src=\"portfolio/$imagem\" alt=\"\">
                            <div class=\"portfolio-overlay\">
                                <h3>$categoria $titulo</h3>
                                <a href=\"port.php?por=$titulo\" class=\"expand\">
                                    <i class=\"fa fa-camera\"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-overlay -->
                        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-thumb -->
                    </div> <!-- /.portfolio-item -->


         ";
                }

                mysql_close();
        ?>

</div>
</div>




        <div class="content-section" id="our-team">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>Últimos Eventos</h2>

                    </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
          <?php
                $c->Conecta();
                $c->SelecionaBase();

                $ex="ultimos";
                $sqq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ultimos_eventos WHERE execao='$ex' order by id desc LIMIT 12");
                while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqq)){
                    $nome = $b['nome_fotos'];
                        $imagem = $b['img'];
                        $categoria = $b['categoria'];
                        $id = $b['id'];
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                print"      

                    <div class=\"portfolio-item col-md-3 col-sm-6\">
                        <div class=\"portfolio-thumb\">
                            <img src=\"ultimos/$imagem\" alt=\"$nome\">
                            <div class=\"portfolio-overlay\">
                                <h3>$categoria $nome</h3>
                                <a href=\"foto.php?ti=$nome\" class=\"expand\">
                                    <i class=\"fa fa-camera\"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-overlay -->
                        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-thumb -->
                    </div> <!-- /.portfolio-item -->

";
}

mysql_close();
?>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<p align="center"><a href="eventos-final.php"><input type="submit" class="mainBtn text-center" value="Ver Mais"></a></p>
</div>

        <div class="content-section1" id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>Contato</h2>

                    </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
                        <p align="center">Envie um e-mail para nós e consulte a disponibilidade e os valores para o seu evento preenchendo o formulário ao lado. Quanto mais detalhes você informar, melhor e mais rápido poderemos responder. Obrigado pela compreensão Atenciosamente Equipe Estudio de Imagem.
                        </p>
                        <ul class="contact-info">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"> (16) 3382-9698</i></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"> (16) 99749-8592</i></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"> contato@egfotografia.com.br</i></li><br>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker">  Matão-SP Rua Maranhão,10<br><a href="https://www.google.com.br/maps?q=Rua+Maranhão,+10,+Matão+-+SP&t=m&z=19" target="_blank"> Ver Mapa Completo </i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- spacing for mobile viewing --><br><br>
                    </div> <!-- /.col-md-7 -->
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <form method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" action="email.php">
                                <p>
                                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nome Completo">
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Informe seu E-mail para entrarmos em Contato"> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Assunto"> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>    
                                </p>
                                <input type="submit" class="mainBtn" id="submit" value="Enviar Mensagem">
                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- /.contact-form -->
                    </div> <!-- /.col-md-5 -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </div> <!-- /#contact -->


        <div class="content-section2 col-md-12" id="contact1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>Área do Cliente</h2>

                    </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
                </div> <!-- /.row -->    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-11 text-center">
                <form method="post" action="logar.php" id="contactform" name="contactform">
                   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                   <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                   <input type="submit" class="main-btn" id="submit" value="Logar">
                </form>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 text-left">
                        Copyright © 2015 Eduardo Gonçalves Fotografia | Design: Leonardo Costa
                    </div> <!-- /.text-center -->

                </div> <!-- /.row -->
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </div> <!-- /#footer -->

        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

e aqui e o código em jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    'use strict';


    /************** Toggle *********************/
    // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $(".menu-first, .menu-responsive"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr("href"),
          offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
          scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 450);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       // Get container scroll position
       var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

       // Get id of current scroll item
       var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
         if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
           return this;
       });
       // Get the id of the current element
       cur = cur[cur.length-1];
       var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

       if (lastId !== id) {
           lastId = id;
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
       }                   
    });



    $(window).scroll(function(){
         $('.main-header').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
     });



    $('a[href="#top"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });


    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      slideshow: true,
      slideshowSpeed: 6000,  
      animation: "fade",
      directionNav: false,
    });


    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
        $('.menu-responsive').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });


    /************** LightBox *********************/
      $(function(){
        $('[data-rel="lightbox"]').lightbox();
      });


});
```

trecho `content-section`:

```
.content-section {
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-left:-10px;
}
```

trecho do active que marca as cores:

```
.main-menu ul li.active a {
 border-top: 3px solid #757f8c;
  color: #757f8c;
}
```

Aqui estão as [imagens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Heme.jpg):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Desculpe a resposta, mas esta é uma comunidade de desenvolvedores, então precisamos de código caso precise de uma ajuda específica. Tente simular o problema no https://jsfiddle.net/ para que possamos visualizar o problema.

Comment: Boa noite Leandro, está bem difícil deduzir o que pode ser, é *altamente* recomendável que leia os seguintes links para que você não venha a ter dificuldades em transmitir problemas futuros para novas perguntas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: vo postar o codigo html e da pagina que faz isto

Comment: postei os codigos junto com as imagens

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se as classes das `divs` de cada *content* estão corretas, me parece que as duas últimas `divs` estão diferentes das demais.

```
<div class="content-section" id="services">
...
<div class="content-section" id="portfolio">
...
<div class="content-section" id="our-team">
...
<div class="content-section1" id="contact">
...
<div class="content-section2 col-md-12" id="contact1">
...
```

Tente seguir o padrão do template, muito provavelmente esta é a fonte do problema.

UPDATE 1: Experimente isso nos dois últimos

```
<div class="content-section" id="contact">
...
<div class="content-section" id="logar">
...
```

Certifique-se de que os *ids* não são referenciados no CSS. Caso sejam, inclua-os.

Comment: já verifiquei isso amigo e esta correto eu não entendo por que ele da o efeito da animação descendo para onde eu cliquei ele só não da o hover nos 2 ultimos

Comment: depois que eu fiz esse edit que você falou ele desceu uma agora ele da o `hover` no contato mas ele não da no área do cliente parece pelo o que eu estou vendo ele não esta dando o `hover` neste por que ele não ocupa a tela inteira

Comment: neste caso é necessário ver o funcionamento da classe _content-section_ para descobrir o motivo da última `div`não ter entrado na regra. Eu chutaria que é o `id`, você pode repetir `id="contact"` na última `div` para observar o comportamento. Se for isso, basta incluí-lo no CSS.

Comment: tipo assim eu to testando aqui já testei o que você falou ai resolvi aumentar o `height` da `div`da área do cliente para isso fiz uma classe igual e troquei o nome a unica diferença nela e o `height` coloquei 700px ai atualizei a pagina e ela desceu e deu o `hover` da pra tipo arrumar isso para ela dar `hover` independente do tamanho?

Comment: torno a repetir, o `hover` deve estar no seu arquivo CSS. Não há como responder sua pergunta sem antes ver o comportamento da classe _content-section_

Comment: vo posta ela aqui o trecho do content-section

Comment: pronto editei a pergunta

Comment: nenhum `hover`?

Comment: o `hover` ele da com o javascript mas e não e `hover` cara e `active` para quando eu clicar ele ficar marcado como `active`. vou editar a pergunta

Comment: prontinha já editei